# Excel date data is not imported correctly into SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, date

I'm trying to import date from excel, which looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFwKG.jpg)

But it somehow show up as nonsense numbers when imported to SQL:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13kww.png)

While no data in my table is similar to this shown data in SQL. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: You defined your column in the import as a `int` not a [date and time data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes). I would suggest you simply bin the data you've imported, and import it again, creating the table with the correct data types this time.

Comment: Hi Larnu, it shows that the data type for the column is nvarchar in the import window but I'm not allowed to fix it. Do you know how to redefined the data type elsewhere?

Comment: That sounds like the date column isn't formatted as a date column in the Excel file as well, but as text, or you have a mixture of data in there, and thus ACE is having to use a string based data type, due to inconsistent data.

Comment: Yes, you are right Larnu. I reformatted it in Excel and it worked now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.